# looking for a cholov yisrael product

Tags: product-recommendation, food, dairy, chalav-yisrael-jewishmilk

Where can I find cholov yisrael evaporated milk, not powdered milk nor condensed, in the central NJ area? I have been unable to locate any.

Comment: Esther Addison, [Welcome to Mi Yodeya](//meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/3887), and thanks for bringing your question here! I hope that you get great answers, and that you look around and find other content here of interest.

Answer (score 3):

I checked with a manager of a large grocery store in Lakewood and in Brooklyn. Unfortunately none of the Cholov Yisroel companies currently produce such a product. Thus it is not available.

Answer (score 1):

It's easy to make. You just simmer the milk in a saucepan and reduce it by 60%. For example reduce from 4 1/2 cups to 2 cups.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. However, this would serve better as a comment considering it does not answer the question as posed. This is especially true considering that the OP might be looking for the prepackaged version in order to store it.

Comment: I figured to add it as an alternative answer since the previous answer stated there the isn't a CY company that makes it.

Comment: You found the scientific answer. Now, if you market it (Is there a Jewish "Shark Tank"?) not only will you make money, but you'd be able to answer this question.

Comment: I don't see why people are complaining that this isn't an answer. The asker asked where to find evaporated milk in central New Jersey, and this answer says where: on one's stovetop.